# To use a DynamicMapping with EntityMapping on RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I would like to add a dynamic mapping on my RestKit schema like described [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#dynamic-object-mapping) but I am using **RKEntityMapping** and not **RKObjectMapping**. **RKEntityMapping** inherits from **RKObjectMapping** according to the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKEntityMapping.html).

My problem that I am not able to find a way to extract the ObjectMapping from the EntityMapping. I do not even know if it is possible or not.

This is the JSON I want to parse :

```
"moment": {
    "id": 23,
    "is_closed": false,
    "created_at": "2013-04-19 19:28:42.533901",
    "updated_at": "2013-04-19 19:28:42.533901",
    "spot_id": "1",
    "spot_type": "Place",
    "place": {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "First place"
    }
}
```

This is my code where I try to map my **EntityMapping** with a **DynamicMapping**

```
RKEntityMapping *momentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Moment" inManagedObjectStore:store];
momentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"momentId"];
[momentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"moment.id" : @"momentId",
                                                          @"moment.name" : @"name",
                                                          @"moment.creator.id" : @"creatorId",
                                                          @"moment.spot_id" : @"spotId",
                                                          @"moment.spot_type" : @"spotType",
                                                          @"moment.is_closed" : @"isClosed",
                                                          @"moment.created_at" : @"createdAt",
                                                          @"moment.updated_at" : @"updatedAt"
                                                          }];

//Add mapping of the place
RKEntityMapping *placeMapping = [APICallPlace RKGetPlaceMappingForManagedObjectStore:store];
[placeMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"moments" connectedBy:@{ @"placeId": @"spotId" }];
//[momentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"place" connectedBy:@{@"placeId": @"placeId"}];
[momentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"moment.place"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"place"
                                                                            withMapping:placeMapping]];
//Add mapping of the establishment
RKEntityMapping *establishmentMapping = [APICallEstablishment RKGetEstablishmentMappingForManagedObjectStore:store];
[establishmentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"moments" connectedBy:@{ @"establishmentId": @"spotId" }];
//[momentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"place" connectedBy:@{@"placeId": @"placeId"}];
[momentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"moment.establishment"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"establishment"
                                                                            withMapping:establishmentMapping]];
```

I would like to attach a dynamic mapping. I tried this way below. I added **???** to show where is my problem. The method **setObjectMapping** requires an RKObjectMapping but I only have a EntityMapping.

```
RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[placeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"spot" toKeyPath:@"spot" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];

// Connect a response descriptor for our dynamic mapping
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dynamicMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"moment" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:(RKObjectMapping *)placeMapping.requestMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:@"spot_type" isEqualTo:@"Place"];


[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:(RKObjectMapping *)establishmentMapping.requestMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:@"spot_type" isEqualTo:@"Establishment"];
```

If anyone has an idea to solve this problem, I would really appreciate to hear it !

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using it all wrong :-) Plus, your key paths would appear to be wrong because you are using `@"mapping"` in both the response descriptor and the mappings...

It looks like you might not even need a dynamic mapping, because you either have a `place` or an `establishment` so the content of `spot_type` doesn't matter...

For the dynamic mapping (if you do need it):

This line:

```
[momentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"moment.place" toKeyPath:@"place" withMapping:placeMapping]];
```

and this one:

```
[momentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"moment.establishment" toKeyPath:@"establishment" withMapping:establishmentMapping]];
```

directly links the `momentMapping` and the `placeMapping` and `establishmentMapping` and you don't want to do that. Instead, what you should be doing is only linking `momentMapping` with your `dynamicMapping` and then the `dynamicMapping` chooses whether `placeMapping` or `establishmentMapping` should really be used.

And the dynamic mapping would be configured with:

```
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:placeMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:@"spot_type" isEqualTo:@"Place"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your so fast answer ! You're right. I have only a Place or an Establishment, but not both in the same time. What you said about linking only momentMapping with my dynamicMapping is exactly what I want. I don't know how to configure the dynamicMapping in order to choose which mapping is the good one because I tried the line-code to wrote but it's not working because placeMapping is not a RKObjectMapping but a RKEntityMapping.

Comment: So you don't need the dynamic mapping. RestKit will just map what you receive and ignore the other relationship mapping...

Comment: An entity mapping is a type of object mapping. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: You're right, that's why I didn't understand.
XCode says :No visible @interface for 'RKDynamicMapping' declares the selector 'setObjectMapping:whenValueOfKeyPath:isEqualTo:'

I think it's not directly linked to RestKit because I've already seen this error before. (I'm a new iOS developer).

Comment: I guess you saw that method online somewhere, it must be from an old version and not available now...

Comment: I don't know it was not working. I used the second option describe [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#dynamic-object-mapping) it seems to work better. I configured the `dynamicMapping` as you said but I don't know how to link my moment directly with this `dynamicMapping`. Am I suppose to add properties to the `placeMapping` and `establishmentMapping` or not at all ?
Thank you for your time. I really appreciate that. :-)

Comment: I don't think you need a dynamic mapping at all from your description, remove it all together...

Comment: Then, remove `moment.` from all of your mapping source keys.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to up-vote and tick answers that helped and solved your question ;-)

Comment: I was searching how to do that actually. I think it's done. I have another question but I'll create a new post for that. Thank you again.

Comment: I have a last question because finally it's not working but I'm close I can feel it ;-) What relationship am I suppose to write on the moment's datamodel ? establishment and place of the moment or spot (type/id) ?

Comment: I don't really understand `spot (type/id)`. You're asking about relationship creation in the Core Data modelling tool?

Comment: I don't know how to call the relation between `moment` and `spot` (which can be `place` or `establishment`). Do I have to set a relationship called  `place` and another called `establishment` or only one called `spot` ?

Comment: You would have 2 different relationships as the destination entities are different.

Comment: Ok. But what I don't understand is how can I link my `moment` to the dynamic mapping ? With which name ? Because you said "only linking momentMapping with your dynamicMapping". This is the only missing part I think.

Comment: I said I don't think you need a dynamic mapping. Why do you think you do need it?

Comment: Complet misunderstanding from me. What you said the first time is working perfectly. I don't know what I did previously and why I was searching something much harder.. Thank you for your time !